# Rsync through the internet

Tags: backup, rsync, internet, drbd

I'm looking for a way to copy files from production server to DRP server via internet. The two servers are in different states. For now, there isn't a lot of data to transfer but I suspect it might go up.

I read a lot about [Rsync](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/) and [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/).

My question are:

1. Which of the two is better for this objective?
2. Is there any better (freeware) tool for doing that?
3. Are there any special problems doing that over the internet??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There should be no issues using rsync, you could also use [dirvish](http://dirvish.org/) which is a better solution in case you want incremental backups to be done.

2) rsync should be enough, but as before better use dirvish as it will give better control in case you need incremental backups.

3) There should be no issues here, rsync and dirvish can use sftp to transfer data thus the transfer should be pretty safe.

Comment: Never heard of rsync using sftp. Did I miss something? Or were you refering to rsync + ssh  (which secures files transfer but makes no use of the sftp protocol)?